# How to read text on a lgo file (eg left, right etc) for Turtle Graphics

Tags: c#, drawing, turtle-graphics, readfile, openfiledialog

I need to create an application which will interpret a subset of the Logo programming language and perform the actions in a Logo program. My application will read a logo program and perform the actions inside the program.  Each line of the logo program only contains 1 logo command. I cannot access or see the logo file and do not know how to read the contents of this lgo file.

These are the commands which have been given:

**Left**: turn the turtle's direction 90 degrees to the left

**Right**: turn the turtle's direction 90 degrees to the right

**Tail**: if the tail is up, put it down and vice versa

**Step**: Move the turtle 1 step in the current direction

```
{
    //Direction values
    const int NORTH = 0;
    const int EAST = 90;
    const int SOUTH = 180;
    const int WEST = 270;

    //Amount to move the turtle 1 step
    const int STEP_AMOUNT = 50;

    //Amount to add to direction when turning
    const int TURN_AMOUNT = EAST;

    //Set direction of turtle to East
    int direction = 90;
    //Status of the tail
    bool isTailUp = true;
    //Current x and y position of the turtle
    Point turtlePos = new Point(0, 0);

    //Filter constant
    const string FILTER = "All Files|*.*|Logo Program Files|*.lgo";

    StreamReader reader;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the application to it's initial state.
    /// </summary>
    private void Initialise()
    {
        pictureBoxDisplay.Refresh();
        direction = 90;
        isTailUp = true;
        turtlePos = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the direction of the turtle 90 degrees to the left.
    /// </summary>
    private void Left()
    {
        //If direction is north then set to west, otherwise just subtract 
        //the turn amount from the current direction
        if (direction == NORTH)
        {
            direction = WEST;
        }
        else
        {
            direction -= TURN_AMOUNT;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the direction of the turtle 90 degrees to the right
    /// </summary>
    private void Right()
    {
        //If direction is west then set to north, otherwise just add 
        //the turn amount to the current direction
        if (direction == WEST)
        {
            direction = NORTH;
        }
        else
        {
            direction += TURN_AMOUNT;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Toggles the state of the tail.
    /// </summary>
    private void Tail()
    {
        isTailUp = !isTailUp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Works out the new position of the turtle when doing a step
    /// based on the current direction of the turtle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The new position of the turtle after doing a step</returns>
    private Point NewTurtlePos()
    {
        //Create the new position at the current turtle position
        Point newPos = new Point(turtlePos.X, turtlePos.Y);

        //Change the x or y position based on the direction
        if (direction == NORTH)
        {
            newPos.Y -= STEP_AMOUNT;
        }
        else if (direction == SOUTH)
        {
            newPos.Y += STEP_AMOUNT;
        }
        else if (direction == WEST)
        {
            newPos.X -= STEP_AMOUNT;
        }
        else
        {
            newPos.X += STEP_AMOUNT;
        }

        return newPos;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make the turtle move by 1 step in the current direction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paper">Where to draw the graphics</param>
    private void Step(Graphics paper)
    {
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

        //Get the new position of the turtle after doing the step
        Point newPos = NewTurtlePos();

        if (isTailUp == true)
        {
            //If the tail is up then just move the turtle to the new position
            turtlePos = newPos;
        }
        else
        {
            //If the tail is down then draw a line to the new position and then
            //move the turtle to the new position.
            paper.DrawLine(pen1, turtlePos, newPos);
            turtlePos = newPos;
        }
    }

    private void openLogoProgramToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = FILTER;
        //show dialog control and check if user clicked on the open button
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Open selected file
            reader = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            //repeat while it is not end of file
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Read line from file
                if (string == )
                {

                }
            }


            //close file
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not too sure how to know/read if the lgo file reads 'left', 'right', 'step', etc. Then perform the command until the end of the file is reached.

For Example:
IF the command is left THEN call Left method, IF command is step THEN call Step method etc

Eventually, the application will draw whatever commands are on the logo program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks! :)

Comment: Assuming there is one command per line, look at `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` that will read the lines of a text file into a string array. Then use `foreach` to iterate over the lines, and a `switch` statement to decide what to do

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you started!
Beware it should be case sensitive...

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    this.GetType().GetMethod(line.Trim())?.Invoke(this, null);
}
file.Close();
```

Cheers